# Is it possible to contact the customers of our application?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I put an application on the App Store, but I do to change the economic model. The application is currently not free, and some users buy it.
Now, I want to turn the application free, but with restrictions, so that the user can buy an In-App purchase to obtain all the features currently provided by my non-free application.

So, there is a problem, the users who bought my app didn't buy any in-app purchase, and when I would turn the app to a free app with restrictions, they will have the restrictions, too, when they make the update of the application.

Is there a way to know who bought the application or to contact them, or to offer to them the In-App Purchase ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you can see every transaction (trace) but supposing you can you would add an option in the app as "i bought the app", this options send you an email with details the user fills (transaction number or anything like that that proves he actually bought it & then you send him a code (redeem code, option in app) threw an email he provides when he contacts you threw "i bought the app" and this code unlocks the features, every code can only be used once of course.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is not going to release customer information to you.

What you should is publish a new application with the same source code. But give it a new title. For example: "Application Name - Lite".

The existing app you pull from the App Store. So now only new people can buy the lite version. And the lite version have the in-purchase option.

If you fix a bug in the source code, you can publish an update and your first customer will appreciate it.